# Delete a row at a certain line number in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am building an app in which I need to delete a table row at a certain line number. I don't want to use or rely on an id, because if I delete a row, the following rows won't "shift down" -- line 8 today could be line 7 tomorrow, but line 8 will still have an id of 8.

How can I write a postgres SQL that essentially does this:

```
DELETE FROM Table
WHERE <row_number> = n;
```

And row_number isn't a real attribute.

Comment: What are "line" and "line number"?

Comment: Do you mean like the row number when viewing data in PGAdmin? Sounds like you're mixing a view row number with record ID.

Comment: OK, I think you are all correct in that I need a better schema instead of trying to rig this thing with what I've got. OID doesn't work correctly -- tried that. The tables don't have primary keys because they are essentially charts, not rows of relational data. But I will add keys to make this easier.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather ill-defined; as Milen comments, what do you *really* mean by "line" and "line number"? I hope you've got `ORDER BY`s in all your queries if you're doing stuff like that. This question also becomes trivial if your rows have primary keys... do yours not? A table with no primary keys is a table that's asking for trouble, and usually indicates a *serious* design flaw.

Anyway, if you want to go full speed ahead, damning the potential problems en route, [the windowing functions in 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/tutorial-window.html) will probably do what you need with minimal fuss. Or you could save yourself a ton of trouble *tomorrow* by writing a better schema *today*.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably the OID:

`DELETE FROM Table
   WHERE oid = n;`

See [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-oid.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the row number of the table as such but should do the desired job.
Perhaps a little more flexible because you can do the delete by date time order or whatever order you like.  I'm going to use this for a recent list.

```
DELETE 
FROM table 
WHERE pk IN 
    (
        SELECT pk 
        FROM  table 
        ORDER BY pk OFFSET n
    )
```

Comment: You probably need a `LIMIT 1` in there.

Answer (score -1):

I'd go for:

```
DELETE FROM Table OFFSET <row_number> limit 1 order by id
```

Comment: PostgreSQL does not support `LIMIT` on a `DELETE` statement.